# Filtering Lists in Scala's Monocle

Tags: scala, lenses, monocle-scala

Given the following code:

```
case class Person(name :String)
case class Group(group :List[Person])

val personLens = GenLens[Person]
val groupLens = GenLens[Group]
```

how can i "filter" out certain Persons from the selection, NOT by index but by a specific property of `Person`, like:

```
val trav :Traversal[Group, Person] = (groupLens(_.group) composeTraversal filterWith((x :Person) => /*expression of type Boolean here */))
```

I only found the `filterIndex` function, which does only include elements from the list based on the index, but this is not what I want.

`filterIndex` takes a function of type: `(Int => Boolean)`

and I want:

`filterWith` (made up name), that takes a `(x => Boolean)`, where x has the type of the element of the list, namely `Person` in this short example.

This seems so practical and common that I assume somebody has thought about that and i (with my, i must admit limited understanding of the matter) don't see why it can't be done.

Am I missing this functionality, is it not implemented yet or just plainly impossible for whatever reason (please do explain if you have the time)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### A bad version

I'll start with a naive attempt to write something like this. I'm using a simple list version here, but you could get fancier (with `Traverse` or whatever) if you wanted.

```
import monocle.Traversal
import scalaz.Applicative, scalaz.std.list._, scalaz.syntax.traverse._

def filterWith[A](p: A => Boolean): Traversal[List[A], A] =
  new Traversal[List[A], A] {
    def modifyF[F[_]: Applicative](f: A => F[A])(s: List[A]): F[List[A]] =
      s.filter(p).traverse(f)
  }
```

And then:

```
import monocle.macros.GenLens

case class Person(name: String)
case class Group(group: List[Person])

val personLens = GenLens[Person]
val groupLens = GenLens[Group]

val aNames = groupLens(_.group).composeTraversal(filterWith(_.name.startsWith("A")))

val group = Group(List(Person("Al"), Person("Alice"), Person("Bob")))
```

And finally:

```
scala> aNames.getAll(group)
res0: List[Person] = List(Person(Al), Person(Alice))
```

It works!

---

### Why it's bad

It works, except…

```
scala> import monocle.law.discipline.TraversalTests
import monocle.law.discipline.TraversalTests

scala> TraversalTests(filterWith[String](_.startsWith("A"))).all.check
+ Traversal.get what you set: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ Traversal.headOption: OK, passed 100 tests.
! Traversal.modify id = id: Falsified after 2 passed tests.
> Labels of failing property: 
Expected List(崡) but got List()
> ARG_0: List(崡)
! Traversal.modifyF Id = Id: Falsified after 2 passed tests.
> Labels of failing property: 
Expected List(ᜱ) but got List()
> ARG_0: List(ᜱ)
+ Traversal.set idempotent: OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Three out of five isn't very good.

---

### A slightly better version

Let's start over:

```
def filterWith2[A](p: A => Boolean): Traversal[List[A], A] =
  new Traversal[List[A], A] {
    def modifyF[F[_]: Applicative](f: A => F[A])(s: List[A]): F[List[A]] =
      s.traverse {
        case a if p(a) => f(a)
        case a => Applicative[F].point(a)
      }
  }

val aNames2 = groupLens(_.group).composeTraversal(filterWith2(_.name.startsWith("A")))
```

And then:

```
scala> aNames2.getAll(group)
res1: List[Person] = List(Person(Al), Person(Alice))

scala> TraversalTests(filterWith2[String](_.startsWith("A"))).all.check
+ Traversal.get what you set: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ Traversal.headOption: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ Traversal.modify id = id: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ Traversal.modifyF Id = Id: OK, passed 100 tests.
+ Traversal.set idempotent: OK, passed 100 tests.
```

Okay, better!

---

### Why it's still bad

The ["real" laws](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.14/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html) for `Traversal` aren't encoded in Monocle's `TraversalLaws` (at least not [at the moment](https://github.com/julien-truffaut/Monocle/pull/357)), and we additionally want something like this to hold:

> For any `f: A => A` and `g: A => A`, `t.modify(f.compose(g))` should equal `t.modify(f).compose(t.modify(g))`.

Let's try it:

```
scala> val graduate: Person => Person = p => Person("Dr. " + p.name)
graduate: Person => Person = <function1>

scala> val kill: Person => Person = p => Person(p.name + ", deceased")
kill: Person => Person = <function1>

scala> aNames2.modify(kill.compose(graduate))(group)
res2: Group = Group(List(Person(Dr. Al, deceased), Person(Dr. Alice, deceased), Person(Bob)))

scala> aNames2.modify(kill).compose(aNames2.modify(graduate))(group)
res3: Group = Group(List(Person(Dr. Al), Person(Dr. Alice), Person(Bob)))
```

So we're out of luck again. The only way our `filterWith` could actually be lawful is if we promise never to use it with an argument to `modify` that might change the result of the predicate.

This is why `filterIndex` is legit—its predicate takes as an argument something that `modify` can't touch, so you can't break the `t.modify(f.compose(g)) === t.modify(f).compose(t.modify(g))` law.

---

### Moral of the story

You could write an unlawful `Traversal` that does unlawful filtering stuff and use it all the time and it's pretty likely that it will never hurt you and that nobody will ever think you are a horrible person. So go for it, if you want. You'll probably never see a `filterWith` in a decent lens *library*, though.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use UnsafeSelect, https://www.optics.dev/Monocle/docs/unsafe_module.html#unsafeselect

```
import monocle.macros.GenLens
import org.scalatest.FunSuite
import monocle.function.all._
import monocle.unsafe.UnsafeSelect

case class Person(name :String, age: Int)
case class Group(group :List[Person])


class Example extends FunSuite{

  test("filter elements of list") {

    val group = Group(List(Person("adult1", 2), Person("adult2", 3), Person("child", 4)))

    val filteredGroup = (GenLens[Group](_.group) composeTraversal each composePrism UnsafeSelect.unsafeSelect(_.name.startsWith("adult")) composeLens GenLens[Person](_.age) set 18) (group)

    assert(filteredGroup.group.filter(_.name.startsWith("adult")).map(_.age) == List(18, 18))
  }

}
```